# sparklyr formula creation error

Tags: r, dplyr, lazy-evaluation, sparklyr

I am testing this tutorial

[Predicting food preferences with sparklyr (machine learning)](https://shiring.github.io/machine_learning/2017/02/19/food_spark)

but in the Modeling section I am getting the following error

*Input code:*

```
library(lazyeval)
for (response in countries) {

  features <- colnames(partitions$training)[-grep(response, colnames(partitions$training))]
  features <- features[grep("_trans|_idx", features)]

  fit <- partitions$training %>%
    filter_(interp(~ var > 0, var = as.name(response))) %>%
    ml_random_forest(intercept = FALSE, response = response, features = features, type = "classification")

...
}
```

*Output:*

```
Error in ml_formula_transformation(): only one of 'formula' or 'response'-'features' should be specified
Traceback:

1. partitions$training %>% filter_(interp(~var > 0, var = as.name(response))) %>% 
 .     ml_random_forest(intercept = FALSE, response = response, 
 .         features = features, type = "classification")
2. withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
3. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
4. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
5. `_fseq`(`_lhs`)
6. freduce(value, `_function_list`)
7. withVisible(function_list[[k]](value))
8. function_list[[k]](value)
9. ml_random_forest(., intercept = FALSE, response = response, features = features, type = "classification")
```

I tried with formula creation, however response is a variable and it should be lazy evaluated, because it feature is the content of response variable (example algeria country)

IN

```
ml_formula <- formula(response ~ features)


  fit <- partitions$training %>%
    filter_(interp(~ var > 0, var = as.name(response))) %>%
  ml_random_forest(ml_formula, type = "classification")
```

out

```
Error in ml_random_forest(., ml_formula, type = "classification"): response is not a column in the input dataset
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Could you come up with a smaller reprex that doesn't involve having to go through the document in the link?

Comment: I can provide you a demo instance online... can you contact with me.... the problem is with the syntax and lazy evaluation or something similar required...